# Nodejs get result of mysql query before returning expressjs callback

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-async

I have this piece of code written in Nodejs ExpressJS.
I would like to get the result of the MySQL query before getting to the last line of the /home call. 
the problem that I tried to use fibers and async libraries and spend a long time on them but no result they are too complicated. I hope that there is someone can explain how to use async in my code or to give the proper way of getting a result of a mysql result before rending a page.

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {

  if (req.session.data.user) {
    db_classic.query('SELECT devices.id ,devices.name ,devices.imei as marker \
                            from devices \
                            left join device_owners \
                            on devices.id = device_owners.device_id \
                            left join users \
                            on users.id = device_owners.user_id \
                            where users.email =? \
                 ', [req.session.data.user], function(err, result) {

      console.log(json(result));
      console.log("user :" + req.session.data.user);
      console.log('/home');
      res.render('home', {
        'username': req.session.data.user,
        'devices': result
      });

    });
  } else {
    console.log('/');
    res.render('index');
  }
  console.log('done');

});
```

Comment: "I would like to get the result of the MySQL query before getting to the last line of the /home call." — You can't.

Comment: "proper way of getting a result of a mysql result before rending a page" — The code in the question already does that.

Comment: the parent process is reaching the last line

Comment: Yes. Before the SQL callback fires. That's how async code works in JS.

Comment: the parent process is reaching the last line < console.log('done'); > before getting the results and rendering the page

Comment: Yes. That's how async code works in JS. It isn't a problem because that call to `log` has nothing to do with the rendering of the page.

Comment: if I console.log( result ); it will give undefined which means there is no results sent for the rendered page

Comment: Well. You aren't doing that. And you can't do that because the function is async. But you have a callback function and you are using it already, so there's still no sign of an actual problem.

Comment: the problem I'm not getting result which i need them in the frondend page!

Comment: if I write <% devices %> it gives undefined however it should be an array of devices!

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/IYczr

Comment: can i call you?

Comment: if the parent process reach the last line and print "done" it means the child process will die and no rendering for the page will happened, so we need to keep the parent process alive until the child process fetch result and render the page

Comment: "it means the child process will die and no rendering for the page will happened" — No. That isn't how asynchronous functions in JS work. Don't the the `console.log` statements inside the callback fire?

Comment: No, it doesn't fire

Comment: … it would probably have been worth mentioning that in the first place. Are there error messages? Is the `json` function defined? What if you `console.log(err, result)` as the first thing you do inside the callback?

Comment: well the issue is that I need the parent process to block itself waiting for the child to die. I don't want to use infinite loops neither cpu unfriendly solutions

Comment: "well the issue is that I need the parent process to block itself waiting for the child to die" — No, it isn't. Node is designed to handle asynchronous functions.

Comment: You seem to be heavily stuck in an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where Y won't fix X. You need to adjust your focus and find out what X really is.

Comment: I thought what called "Promises" could be the right way to solve my problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You've already got a callback. Promises at this stage will just make things more complicated.

Comment: It's true the problem could be solved by ignoring the parent process since it doesn't do anything in the end. but, in some case which I may I face in the future I think the parent process could force me to do stuff unless I have to block it temporally

Comment: Thanks for the help and being patient. So you mean the way I wrote the code is the proper way?